# Training a unet model , but model is not learning

Tags: keras

I am trying to train a segmentation model, But loss saturates at 0.3370 , i am really not sure what to do, can someone please help

This is the model

```
def unet(input_shape=(128, 128, 128), optimizer=Adam, initial_learning_rate=5e-4,
                      loss_function=weighted_dice_coefficient_loss):   

    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    conv1 = UnetConv3D(inputs, 32, is_batchnorm=False, name='conv1')
    pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2 ))(conv1)

    conv2 = UnetConv3D(pool1, 64, is_batchnorm=False, name='conv2')
    pool2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2 ))(conv2)

    conv3 = UnetConv3D(pool2, 128, is_batchnorm=False, name='conv3')
    pool3 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2 ))(conv3)

    conv4 = UnetConv3D(pool3, 256, is_batchnorm=False, name='conv4')
    pool4 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2,2 ))(conv4)

    conv5 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(pool4)
    conv5 = Conv3D(512, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv5)

    up6 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(256, (2, 2,2 ), strides=(2, 2,2 ), kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv5), conv4], axis=1)
    conv6 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv6)

    up7 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(128, (2, 2,2 ), strides=(2, 2,2 ), padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv6), conv3], axis=1)
    conv7 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv7)

    up8 = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(64, (2, 2,2 ), strides=(2,2,2 ), kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv7), conv2], axis=1)
    conv8 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(up8)

    up9    = concatenate([Conv3DTranspose(32, (2, 2,2 ), strides=(2, 2,2 ), kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv8), conv1], axis=1)
    conv9  = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu',  kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(up9)
    conv9  = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit, padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv3D(3, (1, 1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kinit,padding = 'same', name='final', data_format = 'channels_first')(conv9)

    activation_name = 'sigmoid'
    activation_block = Activation(activation_name)(conv10)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[activation_block])
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer(), loss=loss_function)
    return model
```

This is the helper function

```
def UnetConv3D(input, outdim, is_batchnorm, name):
    x = Conv3D(outdim, (3, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_initializer=kinit, padding="same", name=name+'_1', data_format = 'channels_first')(input)
    if is_batchnorm:
        x =BatchNormalization(name=name + '_1_bn')(x)
    x = Activation('relu',name=name + '_1_act')(x)

    x = Conv3D(outdim, (3, 3, 3), strides=(1, 1, 1), kernel_initializer=kinit, padding="same", name=name+'_2', data_format = 'channels_first')(x)
    if is_batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization(name=name + '_2_bn')(x)
    x = Activation('relu', name=name + '_2_act')(x)
    return x
```

And this is the loss function  --

```
def weighted_dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred, axis=(-3, -2, -1), smooth=0.00001):
    """
    Weighted dice coefficient. Default axis assumes a "channels first" data structure
    :param smooth:
    :param y_true:
    :param y_pred:
    :param axis:
    :return:
    """
    return K.mean(2. * (K.sum(y_true * y_pred,
                              axis=axis) + smooth/2)/(K.sum(y_true,
                                                            axis=axis) + K.sum(y_pred,
                                                                               axis=axis) + smooth))
```

My input is (128,128,128), am i doing an obvious mistake? Please let me know if more info needed.

Model summary

---

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 1, 128, 128,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv3D)                (None, 32, 128, 128, 896         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_1_act (Activation)        (None, 32, 128, 128, 0           conv1_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv3D)                (None, 32, 128, 128, 27680       conv1_1_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_2_act (Activation)        (None, 32, 128, 128, 0           conv1_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_1 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 32, 64, 64, 6 0           conv1_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv3D)                (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 55360       max_pooling3d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_1_act (Activation)        (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 0           conv2_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv3D)                (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 110656      conv2_1_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_2_act (Activation)        (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 0           conv2_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_2 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 64, 32, 32, 3 0           conv2_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv3D)                (None, 128, 32, 32,  221312      max_pooling3d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_1_act (Activation)        (None, 128, 32, 32,  0           conv3_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv3D)                (None, 128, 32, 32,  442496      conv3_1_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_2_act (Activation)        (None, 128, 32, 32,  0           conv3_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_3 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 128, 16, 16,  0           conv3_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv3D)                (None, 256, 16, 16,  884992      max_pooling3d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_1_act (Activation)        (None, 256, 16, 16,  0           conv4_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv3D)                (None, 256, 16, 16,  1769728     conv4_1_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv4_2_act (Activation)        (None, 256, 16, 16,  0           conv4_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_4 (MaxPooling3D)  (None, 256, 8, 8, 8) 0           conv4_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)               (None, 512, 8, 8, 8) 3539456     max_pooling3d_4[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)               (None, 512, 8, 8, 8) 7078400     conv3d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_1 (Conv3DTrans (None, 256, 16, 16,  1048832     conv3d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 512, 16, 16,  0           conv3d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 conv4_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)               (None, 256, 16, 16,  3539200     concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_4 (Conv3D)               (None, 256, 16, 16,  1769728     conv3d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_2 (Conv3DTrans (None, 128, 32, 32,  262272      conv3d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 256, 32, 32,  0           conv3d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 conv3_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_5 (Conv3D)               (None, 128, 32, 32,  884864      concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_6 (Conv3D)               (None, 128, 32, 32,  442496      conv3d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_3 (Conv3DTrans (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 65600       conv3d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 128, 64, 64,  0           conv3d_transpose_3[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_7 (Conv3D)               (None, 64, 64, 64, 6 221248      concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_transpose_4 (Conv3DTrans (None, 32, 128, 128, 16416       conv3d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 64, 128, 128, 0           conv3d_transpose_4[0][0]         
                                                                 conv1_2_act[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_8 (Conv3D)               (None, 32, 128, 128, 55328       concatenate_4[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_9 (Conv3D)               (None, 32, 128, 128, 27680       conv3d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
final (Conv3D)                  (None, 3, 128, 128,  99          conv3d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 3, 128, 128,  0           final[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't activation be softmax? As each pixel has one of N labels, but you are using sigmoid. Other than that, do you provide batch as first dimension?

Comment: I have tried with softmax ,same problem , besides i have a diferent model which learns on the data with sigmoid activation , And batch will be the 0th dimension

Comment: You may want to add your training loop as well. What are your target tensors? Those should consist of elements with each being a classification label (so integers values, say 0-4 for segmentation with 5 elements). Have you tried using cross-entropy loss? Can you overfit a single batch with your current setup?

Comment: Currently i am trying to overfit on a single batch, but i am not able to do so, I feel there is something wrong with the model ,because as i mentioned earlier i have another model with a similiar setup which is able to overfit on a single batch, and i have only replaced the model. I mean because i have one model which works and the model is the only thing i have replaced, i am guessing the fault should be in the model itself.No sure though

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Not sure if it helps, but i have posted model summary

Comment: Why does your input has different dimension when compared to output? And shouldn't channels be last in Keras? Or is it some kind of time series you are doing? Furthermore your input_shape was defined with `(128, 128, 128)`, what's up with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195400/discussion-between-ryan-and-szymon-maszke).