# UNET training: accuracy starts over 0.99

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am trying to do some image segmentation using UNET (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56715122/training-a-unet-model-but-model-is-not-learning) but 2D ). However, the accuracy starts really high even at the beginning of epoch 1.

```
32/3616 [..............................] - ETA: 4:59:02 - loss: 0.6761 - accuracy: 0.9964
64/3616 [..............................] - ETA: 5:02:32 - loss: 0.4355 - accuracy: 0.9966
```

Is this normal? For me, it feels like it does not learn!

Which one is indication of learning; loss, accuracy or both?

p.s.: I am using CPU, I will try on GPUs training to speed up.

Comment: No, it seems like something goes wrong. But what- it depends on task you are resolve.

Comment: @IhorKonovalenko, I have raw images. On these images, some areas are marked with masks and the boundary of the mask. Simply, the aim is to teach to learn the area of interest with the raw images with the mask or raw images with boundaries.

Comment: As this is a segmentation task, Accuracy is not a good metric to depend on, a lot of pixels being black and a lot being white will increase the accuracy, loss is the way to go. Also, instead of cross-entropy, in segmentation losses like IOU/dice etc are more suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably dealing with imbalanced dataset. Your network can have the accuracy of 99% when structures you are trying to segment are small (and take, for example, 1% of the image). Then, if your network predicts only 0s, you will get 99% accuracy (because it will be correct to predict 99% of "empty" pixels).

You should use more informative metrics to keep track of your network performance, including Dice score.

Loss is here a better indicator of learning.

Also, training a U-Net for a real life task with CPU will be virtually impossible (would take weeks-months). You should use GPU for good performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed, I have images with only empty pixels. This explains the reason. As soon as I have a computer with GPUs, I will run training on GPUs.